# How is representing an object with a String useful? Inquirt on toString()

Tags: java

Hi beginner in Java here, currently going through some problems in my java textbook and am finding myself using `toString` sometimes, since the book lays out some of the examples like that.

After googling more on the usefulness of `toString()`, i read many SO answers saying that you it was useful for representing an object with a `string`.

Consider the following example which I just made up

```
class Frog{

    private String name;
    private int id;
    public Frog(int id, String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return id + ":" + name;
    }

}

public class DataSet{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Frog frog1 = new Frog(7,"Freddy");
        Frog frog2 = new Frog(5,"Rogers");
        System.out.println(frog1);
        System.out.println(frog2);
    }
}
```

All right pretty cool. toString is being immediately invoked as soon as I create the `frog1, frog 2` objects. Now the first question is
**How is this remotely useful?**

Now consider something else,
Suppose I added my own String method

```
public String imitateToString(){
        return id+":" + name;
    }
```

Now we can do

```
String newFrogOne = frog1.imitateToString();
String newFrogTwo = frog1.imitateToString();
System.out.println(newFrogOne);
```

Isn't this serving the same purpose as `toString()?` I guess what i'm trying to get at is, can't I make another String method and do the same thing as what I did in `toString()?`

Comment: No. Because the default behavior of `PrintStream.print(Object)` is to invoke `Object.toString()`.

Comment: You can make that method for your custom types. However, it's unlikely the 3rd party libraries that you use in your production application will have any knowledge of your types' public interfaces.

Comment: Sorry I haven't learned interfaces yet, what exactly do you mean? That its better to use toString(), since it is a common built in function?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch. Ok fair enough. Why do I want to invoke Object.toString()? How is that useful

Comment: @cresjoy Yes, `Object.toString()` is a special method which is built in in every object. Since every class in java is subclass of `Object`, all the object is ensured to have the method.  What you are doing in `Frog` class is *overriding* the behavior of it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: So toString() is used more for utility? I.e its easy to use, instead of making your own method

Comment: Everything else that converts objects to strings uses that method and only that method, basically.  If you want to use any existing tool that needs to convert your object to a string -- say `System.out.println(Object)` -- you need to override `toString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the title: well, clearly things like

```
date.toString()
```

are useful, no?  If you ever have to display a 'thing' to a user, you're going to have to convert the thing to a string.

In general, everything will one day need to be displayed, even if it's only in debugging trace messages.

With respect to the question about whether you can call a string converter method any other name: well, yes.  But there are cases built in to the language and into common libraries that are going to call toString() and are not going to call yourNotQuiteTheSameMethod().

Trivial example:

```
 String text = "the value is " +  something;
```

Assuming 'something' is not a String, there is a call to something.toString() going to happen there.

Comment: Not sure if date.toString is useful... hence all the Formatters for dates. You are right about using `toString` in debugging, but not everything needs to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

toString() overrides toString() as defined by class "Object", meaning that it can be used if even if "Frog" isn't being used in the context of a "Frog". System.out.println() works in your first example because println() expects an instanceof Object and "toString()" is defined within Object.

For example, with toString(), this is valid:

```
Frog frogAsFrog = new Frog(7,"Freddy");
System.out.println(frogAsFrog);

Object frogAsObject = new Frog(5,"Rogers");
System.out.println(frogAsObject);
```

If you were to use something other than toString():

```
Frog frogAsFrog = new Frog(7,"Freddy");
String newFrogOne = frogfrogAsFrog.imitateToString(); //valid

Object frogAsObject = new Frog(5,"Rogers");
String newFrogTwo = frogAsObject.imitateToString();
//^invalid because "imitateToString()" is not defined in type "Object"
```

Here is a conceptual example of why this is useful:

```
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
objects.add("Hello");
objects.add("World");
objects.add(new Frog(7,"Freddy"));

for (Object object : objects) {
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

That wouldn't work if you defined your imitateToString(), because imitateToString() is not defined in Object.

Answer (score 0):

I think a typical usage would be to get toString() to print the state of an object, a crucial characteristic, or a summery of properties, like in your implementation.

The imitateToString() method provides exactly the same output of course. The difference is that you can safely assume that every object in java will provide the toString method, but you would need to know the specifics of the Frog object to figure out that it provides the imitateToString() method.

So if you wanted to loop through a bunch of different objects and check their status, you can simply call their toString() method like in Zachary's answer without having to assume anything.